# Flutter firebase debugging

Tags: flutter, debugging, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble debugging my Firebase code. When I place a null checker, the debugger returns

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

When I don't place the null checker, dart returns error. `The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'`

This is what I tried first

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(collectionPath)
            .doc(docID)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final bal = snapshot.data?["Balance"]; //this is a number from the firebase collection
          final balance = double.tryParse("$bal");
          final toPay = (balance!) * 100; //the debugging error os on the "balance" with the null checker.
}
```

I also changed the `final` to `double?` but getting the same thing. Can any help me?

Comment: You should check if the snapshot has already data. In your code, `bal` will be `null` if `data` is null or the `Balance` part cannot be parsed as a valid double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check if the `snapshot` `hasData`:

```dart
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      final bal = snapshot.data?["Balance"];
      final balance = double.tryParse("$bal") ?? 0.0;
      final toPay = balance * 100;
      ...
```

Essentially, your `StreamBuilder` might look like:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection(collectionPath)
                .doc(docID)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {

                final bal = snapshot.data?["Balance"];
                ...
                // Do something with the data, this is just an example
                return WidgetToBuild();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Icon(Icons.error_outline);
              } else {
                // Still loading
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            })
```